# How can we verify heap size for running ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am running ElasticSearch Version 6.2.3 and i am increasing heapsize to 4GB in `config\jvm.options` file. Then am restarting my ES, how i can make sure that my ES is running with my modified heapsize. Is there any command to verify the heap-size of ES.

Am running my ES in Windows machine.

Please find my configuration details.

```
## JVM configuration

################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## You should always set the min and max JVM heap
## size to the same value. For example, to set
## the heap to 4 GB, set:
##
## -Xms2g
## -Xmx2g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################

# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms4g
-Xmx4g
```

Answer (score 8):

You can find out the heap size used by each node using the `_cat/nodes` endpoint.

It would look like below:

```sh
host=localhost:9200 #replace with your Elasticsearch URL
curl $host/_cat/nodes?h=heap*
```

This would return an output which should look like below:

```
554.8mb 30 1.8gb
850.9mb 46 1.8gb
  1.7gb 95 1.8gb
```

Column 1 here is heap.current, aka used heap.
Column 2 here is heap.percent, aka used heap in percentage.
Column 3 here is heap.max, aka max heap available to the node.

The `h` query string param allows you to select the column names to display. We are using the `*` wildcard to expand to all the columns that start with the heap prefix.

You can read the documentation here to learn more: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html.

Comment: Why we have 3 values 554 850 and 1.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the JVM arguments used in elasticsearch instance in INFO logs. Make sure that your elastic logging level shows INFO logs.

Comment: You're looking for this line specifically `[2018-07-15T08:35:25,647][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [8Gql5xv] heap size [3.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]` (the 5th one when starting your node) and you can see that the heap size is effectively ~4gb

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the command line arguments used to launch the instance by using either of the options below:

1. Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), and hover over the process name for `java.exe` (launched by `elasticsearch.exe`).  Be sure you have selected "Show Details for All Processes" from the File menu.
2. Run the following command **from an elevated command prompt**: `WMIC PATH win32_process WHERE "caption='java.exe'" GET Commandline`

Both will give you the commandline parameters used to launch the instance.  Look for the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` values.

For more information about these two options, check out [How do I find out command line arguments of a running program?](https://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program)